# Get input text from a table cell using jquery

Tags: jquery, html

I have a table with

```
<TABLE id="dataTable">
    <TR>
        <TD><INPUT type="checkbox" class="chk"/></TD> 
        <TD><INPUT type="text" value="data1"/></TD> 
        <TD><INPUT type="text" value="data2"/></TD>
    <TR>
        <TD><INPUT type="checkbox" class="chk"/></TD> <TD>Data 2</TD> 
        <TD><INPUT type="text"/></TD> 
        <TD><INPUT type="text"/></TD> 
</TABLE>
```

Say I have many rows in the table. I want to fetch the data present in each cell and use it as per my requirements.

I tried doing

```
$(function()
{
   $("#somebutton").click(function()
   {
      $("#dataTable").find('tr').each(function(){
      if($(this).find('input.chk').is(':checked'))
      {
         var val1 = $(this).find('td:eq(1)').html();
         var val2 = $(this).find('td:eq(2)').html();

         alert(val1);
         alert(val2);
      }
   });
 });
});
```

But the output I get from this is as follows

```
<input type="text" value="data1">
<input type="text" value="data2">
```

I just want the output to be given as the value present inside the Text of the cell.
I tried using `.val()` and `.value()` , but it gives me error. Please guide me how to achieve this.

Thanks,

Comment: Where is the button located in the code?

Comment: @shanky try this `var data1 = $(this).find('td:eq(0):input[type="text"]').html();`. Let me know if it solved your issue.

Comment: @androidGenX, thanks for the help. I will upvote your reply :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to access the value of the input, not the value of the td:

```
$(function(){
    $("#onpressofabutton").click(function(){
        var data1 = $(this).find("td:eq(0) input[type='text']").val();
        var data2 = $(this).find("td:eq(1) input[type='text']").val();
    });
});
```

Comment: hey @RononDex. Thanks a lot. This is working perfect for me.

Comment: Thanks a lot. This is working perfect for me too. @RononDex

Answer (score 0):

I have two elements in a table cell

```
<td>
<span>
 <input type ="checkbox"/>
 <input type ="text"/>
</span>
</td>
```

how to get the second element text.  The id is dynamic for both the checkbox / text